AlphaNumeric Sorting Typescript
Input -> const s = ['2.1.1.a', '2.1.a', '2.1.1.d', 'A2.2', 'A2.1', 2.1.1.c', '2.1.b', '2.1.1.b']
Expected out put after sort -> const s = ['2.1.a', '2.1.b', '2.1.1.a', '2.1.1.b', '2.1.1.c', '2.1.1.d', 'A2.1', 'A2.2']
out put after sort using below methods -> const s = ['2.1.b', '2.1.a', '2.1.1.d', '2.1.1.c', '2.1.1.b' , '2.1.1.a', , 'A2.1', 'A2.2']
below are my angular methods I tried to sortto get the output , can some one tell me what is the wrong with this code
private REGEXP_SPECIAL_CHAR = /^[A-Za-z]\d$/;

bubbleSort(collection: any[], property: string = 'code'): any[] {
        let memo = null;

        if (!collection.length) { return collection; }

        for (let outer = 0; outer < collection.length; outer++) {
            for (let inner = 0; inner < collection.length; inner++) {
                if (this.compare(collection[outer][property], collection[inner][property]) === -1) {
                    memo = collection[outer];
                    collection[outer] = collection[inner];
                    collection[inner] = memo;
                }
            }
        }

        return collection;
    }
    private compare(v: any, w: any): number {
        const vCollection = v.split('.');
        const wCollection = w.split('.');
        const depth = Math.min(vCollection.length, wCollection.length);
        let res = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            const vElement = vCollection[i];
            const wElement = wCollection[i];
            const shouldCompareNumbers = !isNaN(Number(vElement)) && !isNaN(Number(wElement));
            const shouldCompareChars = this.isSpecialSymbol(vElement, wElement) || (!isNaN(Number(vElement)) && !isNaN(Number(wElement)));

            if (shouldCompareNumbers) {
                if (Number(vElement) < Number(wElement)) {
                    res = -1;
                    break;
                } else if (Number(vElement) > Number(wElement)) {
                    res = 1;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (shouldCompareChars) {
                if (vElement < wElement) {
                    res = -1;
                    break;
                } else if (vElement > wElement) {
                    res = 1;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (vElement < wElement) {
                    res = 1;
                    break;
                } else if (vElement > wElement) {
                    res = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (res === 0) {
            // check depth
            if (vCollection.length > wCollection.length) {
                res = 1;
            } else if (vCollection.length < wCollection.length) {
                res = -1;
            } else {
                res = 0;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    private isSpecialSymbol(v: string, w: string): boolean {
        return this.REGEXP_SPECIAL_CHAR.test(v) || this.REGEXP_SPECIAL_CHAR.test(w);
    }



btw, why is at first place the number before letter and later vice versa?

That is the input array I am receiving, and I do not have control over it.

in first place means in the string after sorting, like '2.' before 'A' and later in the array after sorting '2.1.b', '2.1.1.a'.

If yours numbers have always the same digits, you can replace the [a-z] by 0[a-z], sort and replace again
sort(s:string[])
{
   return s.map(x=>x.replace(/([a-z]+)/g,'0$1'))
           .sort()
           .map(x=>x.replace(/0([a-z]+)/g,'$1'))
}

The same digits mains that you can not to have, e.g.
2.1.3 and 2.10.3 but yes 2.01.3 and 2.10.3
